# UDF function taking much time

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame like that:

```
SCORE = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
      ('a', "Joe", 1),
      ('b', "Doe", 2),
      ('c', "Carl", 3),
      ('d', "CJ", 4),
      ('e', "Tom", 5),
    ], 
      StructType(
        [
            StructField("id", StringType(), False),
            StructField("user", StringType(), False),
            StructField("score", IntegerType(), False),
        ]
    )
)
```

| id | user | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Joe | 1 |
| b | Doe | 2 |
| c | Carl | 3 |
| d | CJ | 4 |
| e | Tom | 5 |

I have written a UDF to calculate a percentile_score, and it's based on the whole score column. And it's working, is generating a new column called percentile_score:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, collect_list


def calculate_percentile(user_score, score_list):
    data_prs_score.sort()
    scores_count = len(score_list)

    cumulative_frequency = 0
    frequency = 0
    for score in score_list:
        if score == user_score:
            frequency += 1
        elif score > user_score:
            break

        cumulative_frequency += 1

    return (cumulative_frequency - (0.5 * frequency)) / scores_count


def make_score_list(score_list):
     return udf(lambda user_score: calculate_percentile(user_score, score_list), FloatType())
SCORE.withColumn('percentile_score', make_prs_score_list(SCORE.select(collect_list('score')).collect()[0][0])(col('score'))).show()
```

My problem is, this function is taking 1 hour to run.

I think the reason that is taking so long is that I'm using the collect() on the UDF. However, I can't see another way to build that.

So I was wondering what kind of optimization I can do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [percent_rank](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percent_rank.html) to calculate the percentile of each row:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

SCORE.withColumn("percentile_score", 
  F.percent_rank().over(Window.orderBy("score"))) \
  .show()
```

prints

```
+---+----+-----+----------------+                                               
| id|user|score|percentile_score|
+---+----+-----+----------------+
|  a| Joe|    1|             0.0|
|  b| Doe|    2|            0.25|
|  c|Carl|    3|             0.5|
|  d|  CJ|    4|            0.75|
|  e| Tom|    5|             1.0|
+---+----+-----+----------------+
```

However the following warning will appear:

```
WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

Like the warning says all data will be colleted into a single partition and so you lose (temporarily) the parallelism of Spark. But chances are that this approach is still faster than the UDF.